# Daily high score using NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

How do I create a daily high score using `NSUserDefaults`?
I want to make the high score reset at a certain time each day.

```
if(currentScore>currentHighScore)
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setDouble:currentScore forKey:_highScoreLabel.name];
    [defaults synchronize];
    currentHighScore=currentScore;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save a timestamp with the high score. Every time a new score is submitted, check if the timestamp is more than 24*60*60 seconds old. If it is, zero the old high score. Then resume checking if the new high score is larger. This should work regardless of local time zones. In pseudo-code something like this:

```
is time stamp > 1 day old?
    yes: zero old high score

is new high score > old high score ?
    yes: replace old high score with new high score
         update time stamp to current time
```